# Android App placed on screen when swiping left on the homescreen

Tags: java, android

How to make an Android app that will be placed on one of the home screens, for example, like LG SmartBulletin which opens when you swipe left on the homescreen.

I've been trying to find solution for quite some time now, but since I'm a beginner in app development I might just not know what to look for.

Comment: Do you mean something like a widget?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if it's a widget. Could you please do a google search "LG SmartBulletin" and see how it looks/works? Heres yt video, just at the beggining you can see how it's opened with swipe to the left (0:03 seconds): watch?v=n3fV17JkegE

Comment: I see, google has the same kind of thing. I'm afraid the only way to do that is by creating your own launcher, and I don't know if you want to go that far.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely not gonna be building a launcher. Would it be possible to make a widget that will be full screen so it kind of mimics that?

Comment: I have never tried or researched such a thing, but I think it would be possible.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I'm gonna do research on my own about that topic.